# Mahara ePortfolio - How to embed background music using the "Some HTML" Block

Tags: html, audio, mahara

I'm a student that is facing a problem while using my University's version of Mahara. I uploaded an audio file onto my ePortfolio, and tried to use it in my HTML code.

I've been trying `<embed>`, `<audio>`, and `<video>` tags but it seems like they are not supported. I see that Mahara uses flowplayer to display internal media, but I do not have any idea on how to use it while autoplaying and looping the audio.

So, I decided to go with the "Some HTML" block instead of the "Internal Media" block. One example I did is this:

```
<object data="/artefact/file/download.php?file=392549" type="audio/mpeg" width="400" height="315">
<param name="src" value="/artefact/file/download.php?file=392549">
<param name="controller" value="true">
<param name="loop" value="true">
<param name="autoplay" value="true">
<param name="autostart" value="true">
<param name="scale" value="aspect">
</object>
```

I wanted to autoplay and loop the audio, so Internal Media or External Media isn't an option anyway. Just how can I do it with HTML on Mahara? Does it filter these codes and blocks them? I'm new to this, and I'm really stuck.

Answer (score 0):

try it , sample code

```
<audio controls loop>
  <source src="my.mp3">
  <source src="mu2.mp3>

</audio>
```

Comment: you can add audio tracks